# Can anyone explain logic inside trigger exception

Tags: apex, trigger, adderror

```java
trigger accountDeletion on Account (before delete) {
    // Prevent the deletion of accounts if they have related opportunities.
    for (Account a : [SELECT Id FROM Account
                     WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity) AND
                     Id IN :Trigger.old]) {
        Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).addError(
            'Cannot delete account with related opportunities.');
    }
}
```

Can anyone please explain the below line in apex trigger?

```
for (Account a : [SELECT Id FROM Account
                 WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity) AND
                 Id IN :Trigger.old])
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I've edited your question to make it easier to read (formatting the code as code blocks, mostly). I think you'll find you'll get a better response and better answers if you take some time to go into more detail about what precisely you don't understand about the indicated code. [edit] your question to include that.

Answer (score 5):

This trigger prevents to delete account records which have related (child) opportunities records.

The below SOQL is not optimized but what it is doing is it is getting all the accounts that have an opportunity record.

```
[SELECT Id FROM Account
                 WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity) AND
                 Id IN :Trigger.old]
```

If we break it up then the below SOQL will return all account ids from opportunities.

```
(SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity)
```

and trigger.old has deleted account ids.

```
[SELECT Id FROM Account
                     WHERE Id IN (*soql which will bring all account ids*) AND
                     Id IN :Trigger.old]
```

As there is **AND** between both where conditions so it will only return accounts where account id is in both sets (account Ids return from opportunity soql and trigger.old)

If I had to write this trigger then I would have done something like the below.

```
trigger accountDeletion on Account (before delete) {
       // Prevent the deletion of accounts if they have related opportunities.
       for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity
                         WHERE AccountId IN :Trigger.old]) {
        Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.AccountId).addError(
                'Cannot delete account with related opportunities.');
    }
}
```